# How to create two column and with auto number in jasper report to excel?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Hello i have a problem to create report that need to display as two column, but my output is like this

[image]

the focus is the auto numbering value, anyone could help me??

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without reviewing some code but it looks like your code is entering your entires by alternating columns. You should fill the first column with entries before moving onto the second column (to achieve your desired numbering).

Comment: my code is standar just retrieve valuefrom database, but in jasper report properties i change the value of column properti become 2 and page orientation become horizontal i follow this example link to create report